# User Profile Sync - Certain Properties not syncing 

Tags: user-profile, profile-sync, user-profile-property

I've followed Spence Harbar's Rational guide to implementing Profile Sync.
Everything seems fine until further inspection.

The following properties don't sync: *Job Title; Proxy Address; Office Location; Past Project; Skills; Schools & interests*

Error message: There was a problem retrieving data for this field. Updating vaules in this field is disabled temprarily. You can still update values in other fields.

I've removed and recreated the Service Application but the error still occurs.
Any thoughts??

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The usual suspect is proxy address (single value field) as this is actually mapped to proxyadresses (multi field). Consider mapping to SIP address instead.

Some of the other fields are not typically mapped to AD since they are often mapped to taxonomies.